# Issue with sql query (not picking up parameter)

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I have the following code in c# for sql insert:

```
using (DM dbManager = new DM())
{
    dbManager.Command.CommandText = @"Insert into TransactionLog(TransactionNumber,Amount
    ,studentID) Values (@trnumber,@amount,@studentID) ; SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() ;";
    dbManager.Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@trnumber", txnref);
    dbManager.Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@amount", amount);
    dbManager.Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@studentID", 
                                           Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey.ToString());

    id = Convert.ToInt32(dbManager.Command.ExecuteScalar());
}
```

But failing to understand why am i getting this error:

```
 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The parameterized query '(@trnumber 
 nvarchar(4000),@amount nvarchar(5),@studentID nvarcha' expects the 
 parameter '@trnumber', which was not supplied.
```

Because the parameter is clearly in the query i tried changing the name of parameter same issue.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is `DM` exactly? Can you please show it's structure as well?

Comment: @SonerGönül that is a class to care of SqlConnection etc that is working fine i have a few queries above the this one a lot till i reach this point.

Comment: If `txnref` is null, then the `AddWithValue` will mean that the `SqlValue` property of the parameter is null, and it is as if the parameter is not passed (remember `null` in c# and `NULL` in the DB are not the same thing). I would personally use the more strongly type method - `dbManager.Command.Parameters.Add("@trnumber", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 4000).Value = txnref ?? string.Empty`

Comment: the one of the variable is getting null..so it should specify with DBNull.Value..i hope the below answer can sort out the issue

Comment: Or if it should be `DBNull` rather than an empty string - `dbManager.Command.Parameters.Add("@trnumber", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 4000).Value = string.IsNullOrEmpty(txnref) ? (object)DBNull.Value : (object)txnref;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(txnref))
            {
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@trnumber", DBNull.Value); 
            }
            else
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@trnumber", txnref);
```

Comment: Ok let me check it should have been null ... but lets c

Comment: @SonerGönül i hope this answer can sort out the issue..if no data is there in the string we should pass DBNull.Value to the parameter to make it database null value

Answer (score 0):

Try to put  `DBNull.Value` if value is empty it will work! Also check your column accepts NULL